# Balls in boxes: a variation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

We have $n_1$ indistinguishable balls of type $1$, $n_2$ of type $2$, $n_i$ of type $i$ ($i=1, \ldots, m$) to distribute among $k$ distinct boxes. No box can be left empty or contain balls of more than one type.

How many ways?

Comment: There are no constraints on the number of balls: it may be smaller or larger than the number of boxes. Also, the boxes have infinite capacity.

Comment: Is it at all useful to you to observe that it’s $$\sum_{\langle b_1,\ldots,b_m\rangle}\binom{k}{b_1,\ldots,b_m}\prod_{i=1}^m\binom{n_i-1}{b_i-1}\;,$$ where the sum is taken over all weak compositions of $k$ into $m$ parts?

Comment: Yes, I don't think there is a closed form for this.

Comment: Let me make that an answer, then, so that this question gets off the unanswered list.

Comment: It looks like you have created two accounts, one registered (this), and one unregistered. If you want these accounts to be merged, the instructions [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) tell you how to initiate that.

Answer (score 1):

For each $m$-tuple of non-negative integers $\langle b_1,\ldots,b_m\rangle$ such that $b_1+\ldots+b_m=k$ there are

$$\binom{k}{b_1,\ldots,b_m}$$

ways to choose $b_i$ boxes to receive balls of type $i$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$. The usual stars and bars calculation yields $\binom{n_i-1}{b_i-1}$ distributions of the $n_i$ balls of type $i$ in $b_i$ boxes, so altogether the number of distributions is

$$\sum_{\langle b_1,\ldots,b_m\rangle}\binom{k}{b_1,\ldots,b_m}\prod_{i=1}^m\binom{n_i-1}{b_i-1}‌​\;,$$

where the sum is taken over all weak compositions of $k$ into $m$ parts. I’m far from expert, but I’m doubtful that there’s a closed form for this.